# How do I auto-submit a form with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, forms, greasemonkey, submit, form-submit

I'm trying to autosubmit a form with greasemonkey however I'm not sure how to do it with this button.
The button seems to have the following properties

```
a class="blue-button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Form.submit(this);"
```

and the only form I see above is

```
<form xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:s="http://www.blizzard.com/ns/store" action="/account/management/add-game.xml" autocomplete="off" method="post">
```

The page is [here](https://us.battle.net/account/management/add-game.xml) you can use "email9999@trash2009.com" and "a1a1a1a1" as a login.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
```

Note that this will only work if the first form on the page. You can increase the array index to [1] if you need to, or loop through the array looking for the right form.

Comment: Similarly, you could use document.nameOfYourForm.submit().  That would submit a specific form without having to worry about the correct index.  This assumes you can give your form a name.

Comment: For some reason `document.nameOfYourForm.submit();` did not work for me. However, `var myForm = document.getElementByID('nameOfYourForm'); myForm.submit();` worked beautifully. Thanks, james.garriss!

Answer (score 1):

After you have got the username and password fields filled in, do this:

```
unsafeWindow.Form.submit(document.getElementsByClassName('submit')[0]);
```

Check `unsafeWindow` documentation [here](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow).