# Submit form using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, greasemonkey

The first time, each day, I try to access a web page at work, I get redirected to an internally hosted web page with the IT guidelines and a form with two buttons "Agree" and "Disagree". Clicking "Agree" then allows external internet access for that day and sends you to the site you were originally looking for.

I want to make a Greasemonkey script that auto-submits the form, since I already have a batch file starting up all my normal apps on boot and this would allow me to just leave the PC while it's doing its 20 minute daily start-up ;)

The page only has the one form:

```html
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" value="I Agree" class="agree" onsubmit="submitonce(this)" /> 
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:window.close();" value="I Disagree"
  class="disagree"/>
</form>
```

And not sure if it matters, since I only need the click, but the function `submitonce` is:

```js
function submitonce(theform) {
  //if IE 4+ or NS 6+
  console.log("Submitting");
  if (document.all || document.getElementById) {
    //screen thru every element in the form, and hunt down "submit" and "reset"
    for (i = 0; i < theform.length; i++) {
      var tempobj = theform.elements[i];
      if (tempobj.type.toLowerCase() == "submit" ||
        tempobj.type.toLowerCase() == "reset")
        //disable em
        tempobj.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I have the rest of the source, but it doesn't look like there is anything else relevant. I haven't really coded before in Greasemonkey/JS, so any help would be appreciated. I'm playing around with [an existing userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/86606) that uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to click the button.

Obviously I don't care if it's a virtual "click" or just a trigger of the submit function, since I'd say they are the same thing aren't they?

Comment: What browser(s) do you intend to use it on?

Comment: They're not the same, `submit()` doesn't send the name and value of the submit button with the data.

Comment: Taking a second look at your html, I don't think `input` elements have an `onsubmit` attribute.

Comment: It's to be used in Firefox, though I imagine something this simple would work in Chrome too. As for the onsubmit attrib, it's not my code, but hey maybe that function actually does nothing it just the submit moves users on :p

Comment: @vbevan, the function `submitonce()` is only disabling the `submit` and `reset` buttons. Doesn't have anything with actual form submission. Anyway, your best bet is dda's answer.

Comment: @dda, each time you've edited this, you've added error(s) to the presentation markup and/or JS code that weren't in the OP's post.  Please be more careful, and refrain from editing code in questions.  You may be erasing the error (although not in this case).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I auto-submit a form with Greasemonkey?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615186/how-do-i-auto-submit-a-form-with-greasemonkey)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be a simple job:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           myscript
// @namespace      whatever
// @include        http://path to the internal page
// ==/UserScript==

document.forms[0].submit();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try in the morning when I login.

Answer (score 1):

Got some help from a friend who said this should work, though it's not nearly as simple as the answer from dda. Apparently this works in Chrome:

```
function ClicktheButton(obj) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  var cancelled = !obj.dispatchEvent(evt);      
/*

  if(cancelled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault
    alert("cancelled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault
    alert("not cancelled");
  }
  */
}

var StupidButton = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"][value="I Agree!"]');
ClicktheButton(StupidButton);
```

And it would also need the includes etc. that GreaseMonkey scripts always have.

Comment: If this works, and dda's answer doesn't, then the question omitted some key javascript.  The `onsubmit` for an `<input>` already looks like a transcription error as that's not valid HTML and would not fire in most (¿all?) browsers.

Comment: StupidButton. Love this.